# is "calling functions in data structure" possible in haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, data-structures

i have some functions(charfreq,wordfreq,charcount,wordcount,parerror) and i want to use it in dataStructure with the given string.But how can i do it? I'm trying in these and many way ,but i got all error .Thanks in advance .

```
data StrStat = StrStat  { charfreq :: [( Char , Int )] 
                        , wordfreq :: [([ Char ] , Int )] 
                        , charcount :: Int 
                        , wordcount :: Int 
                        , parerror::Maybe Int 
                        }


analyze :: [Char] -> StrStat
analyze x = StrStat { charfreq = (charfreq x) {-this line gives error-}
                    , wordfreq = (wordfreq x)
                    , charcount = (charcount x)
                    , wordcount = (wordcount x)
                    , parerror = (parerror x) 
                    }
```

error message is : `` Syntax error in input (unexpected `=') ``

```
analyze :: [Char] -> StrStat
analyze x = StrStat { "charfreq" = (charfreq x)
                    , "wordfreq" = (wordfreq x)
                    , "charcount" = (charcount x)
                    , "wordcount" = (wordcount x)
                    , "parerror" = (parerror x) 
                    }
```

when i tried previous one , i got the same error at the same line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error I get for your first version is

```
Couldn't match expected type `StrStat' with actual type `[Char]'
In the first argument of `charfreq', namely `x'
In the `charfreq' field of a record
In the expression:
  StrStat
    {charfreq = (charfreq x), wordfreq = (wordfreq x),
     charcount = (charcount x), wordcount = (wordcount x),
     parerror = (parerror x)}
```

Which makes sense to me, as you're applying your getters (all defined in your `data StrStat` declaration, for example, `charfreq :: StrStat -> [( Char , Int )]`) are being called on data of type `[Char]`, rather than on a `StrStat` value.

The `charfreq =` and such are keyword-based arguments for setting the various fields of the `StrStat`, and need to be given the appropriate value (e.g. `[(Char, Int)]`) on their RHS.

What I'm guessing you're trying to do is to construct a `StrStat` value, which you could do by constructing appropriate values:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.List

data StrStat = StrStat  { charfreq :: [( Char , Int )]
                        , wordfreq :: [([ Char ] , Int )]
                        , charcount :: Int
                        , wordcount :: Int
                        , parerror::Maybe Int
                        }

freq :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
freq = map (head &&& length) . group . sort

analyze :: [Char] -> StrStat
analyze x = StrStat { charfreq = freq x
                    , wordfreq = freq $ words x
                    , charcount = length x
                    , wordcount = length $ words x
                    , parerror = Nothing
                    }
```

~

Comment: The OP states that he has functions like `charfreq` already defined, so the code makes sense to me. But if I try to do that, the error I get is “Multiple declarations of `charfreq'”. Note that the error you got doesn't match the one in the question.

Comment: @svick: good point.  I don't know how to recreate the OP's error.

Comment: @svick: If `charfreq` was imported from another module, you don't get an error until you try to use it.

Comment: @hammar: but even then, I get a ``Ambiguous occurrence `charfreq'`` error, not a `Syntax error in input` error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it wasn't my error i find it .When i delete the new line characters and write it in  one line , i eliminate one of my error.Then i changed my function because where function analyze definition exists in strStat i used same names for both functions and names.I was trying to make twice function definition by mistake.Because i had already defined functions(wordfreq,charfreq,etc.) at the following lines. Then it worked.Thanks for your interest